# In Julia, if I delete! a key and value from a dictionary, will it re-allocate the dictionary?

Tags: julia

Specifically, I'm interested in speed.  If I remove an entry from a dictionary, will it immediately re-allocate the space used by the dictionary?  Would it be faster to just set the value to nothing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you `delete!` an entry from the dictionary then it is not re-allocated. Actually dictionary currently does not support shrinking (even `empty!` does not shrink it) - it can only grow if needed.

This means that you have added a lot of entries to the dict and then removed them then sometimes it would save memory to copy these remaining elements to a new dictionary element by element (but not using `copy` as it will create copy with the memory footprint that is the same as the source).

Note, however, that if keys or values are not bits type then removing an entry from a dictionary will remove a reference to it (which means that Julia will be able to garbage collect them if there are no other references to them).